# mysql "grant all" vs "grant all privileges"

Tags: mysql

what is the difference between these two commands?

```
GRANT ALL ON druid.* TO 'druid'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'diurd';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO druid@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'diurd';
```

Answer (score 17):

They are equivalent with respect to the privileges syntax; `PRIVILEGES` is optional. [Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-privileges)

The scope of those permissions, however, is different. One command gives privileges on all databases (`*.*`) and the other gives them only on tables in database `druid` (`druid.*`).

In addition, one allows connections only from `localhost`, but the other allows them from anywhere (`%`).

Finally, `druid@'%'` will give a syntax error; you need quotes around `druid`.

As a best practice, make the permissions as limited as possible (local-only, with permissions to do as little as possible in as few places as possible).